# Ubuntu 20.04: Alt + Tab behaviour with Java application

Tags: 20.04

After I switched to Ubuntu 20.04 I have another weird change. This time is alt+tab that doesn't work as expected.
If I switch between the file explorer and the document viewer I can keep going back and forth easily (alt+tab, to go to the second, alt+tab to go back to the first). If I have a third application opened that's using Java, it's like it's not stored in the memory of the "tab manager" (sorry I have no idea how it's managed). Once I alt+tab out of the Java application, I cant alt+tab back, but I have to tab once or twice, depending on which position it is on the list of available applications.

It seems to happen only with Java applications (Swing I believe)